# Convert values of column to new column

Tags: r

I have this dataframe and I want to convert the values of the first column to another column. This is the data.frame :

```
    scheme          value
1   TS:VAT  FR46351273019
2 TS:REGNO 35124658210293
```

I tried to use dcast from the library reshape2 but the result was not satisfying :

```
> reshape2::dcast(lTS$Identifiers,value ~ scheme)
           value       TS:REGNO        TS:VAT
1 35124658210293 35124658210293          <NA>
2  FR46351273019           <NA> FR46351273019
```

I need the end result to look like this :

```
           TS:VAT       TS:REGNO
1   FR46351273019 35124658210293
```

Can you please help me ?

Comment: using `tidyr` could you do `pivot_wider(lTS$Identifiers, names_from = scheme, values_from = value)`?

Comment: It works, thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Comment: Or duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer so I can mark it as solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
lTS$Identifiers %>%
    group_by(scheme) %>%
    spread(scheme, value)
```

Comment: Both your solution and the one from Ben's comment work, thanks.